# Efficient implementation of Non-Maximum Suppression

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, iteration

I would like to know is there is a  way to do this:

```
oneInter[{keep_, rest_, threshold_}] := 
  Module[{rest1, keep1},
   keep1 = Prepend[keep, rest[[1]]];
   rest1 = Delete[rest, 1];
   {keep1, 
    Select[
      rest1, 
      checkCond[First@keep1[[1]], #[[1]]] < threshold &], 
    threshold}];

result = NestWhile[oneInter, {keep, rest, threshold}, Length @ #[[2]] > 0 &]
```

in a faster way. Here are some examples on the input

```
rest = {{{113.562, 132.359, 36.1574, 92.3191, 92.8595}, 
  0.999996}, {{114.71, 107.947, 39.064, 89.5065, 92.5914}, 
  0.999995}, {{67.1904, 125.644, 30.7171, 94.6351, 90.7846}, 
  0.999992}, {{118.388, 104.597, 38.9507, 90.4049, 92.5298}, 
  0.999991}, {{70.6357, 109.998, 33.0017, 107.651, 94.0905}, 
  0.999991}};
threshold = 0.5
```

As you can see, the rest list is sorted by the second axis. Basically, the rest list contains the coordinates of the rectangles and checkCond computes the intersection area between the pairs of the rectangles.
The real size of rest List is 6000 and the final order of the elements in keep does not matter.

Every evaluation of the checkCond  takes about 1e-4 and the function is compilable.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I think it would be easier to help if you provide an example of the data this operates over and the kind of `checkCond` you  will use.

Comment: A description in words can't hurt either :)

Comment: What is `checkCond`?

Comment: checkCond returns a number between 0 and 1

Comment: I second the request for representative examples. We need to know whether `rest` list is [packable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/14303)? Is it sorted in any way? How many elements does it have? Does order, in which elements in final `keep` list end-up, matter? Is `checkCond` compilable? Is it fast compared to other operations in iteration? `checkCond[First@keep1[[1]], #[[1]]] < threshold &` code seems to give a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) on `rest`, is this relation transitive? All above details can greatly affect performance.

Comment: I apologise if it is evident but I fail to make out what are the dimensions/initial value of `keep`?

Comment: Initially , it is an empty list.  The task is to gather in order some of the elements of the rest which satisfy to checkCond .

Comment: It seems that, modulo ordering, your function is doing: `DeleteDuplicates[rest, checkCond[First@#1, First@#2] >=  threshold &]`, is that the case?

Comment: We still need to know more about `checkCond`. If you have one fixed `checkCond`, could you add its definition to your question? If you need your code working for various different `checkCond` functions then try to add definition of a representative example. I think the most important  thing is whether `checkCond[First@#1, First@#2] <  threshold &` gives a transitive relation, if so, we might go from $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ to $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$. If not, we might still be able to use some tricks, like binning, to get average complexity down, even if worst case will remain unchanged.

Comment: are you using 5 numbers to represent a `Rectangle`? how to do you calculate/compare their areas?

Comment: @user42582 Yes, 5 coordinates, {central_x,central_y,width,height,angle }. The calculation of area consists of finding the intersection points and obtaining the convex polygon and then after it's easy - just applying the formulas with the determinants http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_convex_polygon.htm

Comment: You are basically walking this list, and discarding elements (rectangles) whose intersection with any prior rectangle still on the list exceeds some threshold? In other words, trying to come up with a maximal subset of (up to some threshold) pairwise non-intersecting rectangles? (I use "maximal" in the poset sense here.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, I am doing exactly that. Actually, I am trying to implement Non-Maximum Suppression Algorithm here

Comment: I think there is ample info here to work with, so asking people not to close this.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. OP provided missing relevant information in edits.

Answer (score 4):

One can do this in a procedural manner. A direct version did not give much (it was about the same speed as the original code). Instead I'll show a method that works only with the list of first (5-tuple) elements. The benefit is one can use `Compile` and that gives a quite measurable speed gain.

I use a dummy function for the `checkCondC`. If the max value of the difference of two 5-tuples is less than some threshold, we say the condition fails and do not add the second arg to the list under construction.

This version constructs the list of keepers, and for every new 5-tuple in the original list, tests against keepers before determining whether to add the new on or move on. It is an O(n^2) algorithm but does not have excessive costs from creating/destroying intermediate lists. We simply create an output of the same dimensions as the input, and replace dummy elements by keepers while maintaining a caount of how many keepers we have at any step.

```
checkCondC = 
  Compile[{{ll1, _Real, 1}, {ll2, _Real, 1}}, Max[Abs[ll1 - ll2]]];

maxNonintersectingC = Compile[{{ll, _Real, 2}, {eps, _Real}}, Module[
    {res = ConstantArray[0., Dimensions[ll]], next, max = 1, good},
    res[[1]] = ll[[1]];
    Do[
     next = ll[[j]];
     good =
      Catch[Do[
        If[checkCondC[res[[k]], next] < eps,
         Throw[False]]
        , {k, max}];
       True];
     If[good, max++; res[[max]] = next];
     , {j, Length[ll]}];
    Take[res, max]
    ], CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Now we take a large example.

```
m = 8000;
inlist = Map[{{1, 1, 1/3, 1, 1}*Most[#], 1/120*Last[#]} &, 
   RandomReal[{80, 120}, {m, 6}]];
```

Check that these look a bit like the elements in the original post.

```
In[282]:= inlist[[1 ;; 3]]

(* Out[282]= {{{114.210179264, 94.9872032272, 30.742668711, 
   83.7376433634, 119.920328664}, 
  0.928968044627}, {{104.641626332, 92.2701423248, 29.4891773984, 
   114.993318079, 80.4115524547}, 
  0.960390210004}, {{90.6277601511, 98.6345852935, 30.8461476176, 
   85.7636679809, 111.535125216}, 0.868401515828}} *)
```

Timing:

```
Timing[
 mx = Reverse[maxNonintersectingC[inlist[[All, 1]], eps]];]
Length[mx]

(* Out[283]= {0.096, Null}

Out[284]= 512 *)
```

If we do not compile to C it is still fairly fast, at around 0.27 seconds. By contrast, my pedestrian non-compiled version took around 6.3 seconds.

It is not too difficult to add support for retaining those second elements in the lists. One way would be to feed them in as a separate vark 1 list of reals, `Append` the jth such element to the jth list when that list is a keeper, and appropriately restructuring after the compiled part is finished.

Answer (score 1):

I think that any gains in performance will have to be squeezed out from the `checkCond` function-which is not available at the moment. A marginally-if at any-better version of `oneInter`, that I can think of, is

```
With[{threshold = 0.5},
  selectQ = checkCond[#1, #2] < threshold &
 ];
select = With[{sel = #2}, Select[#1, selectQ[sel, #] &]] &;
oneInter[{keep_, rest_}] := With[{first = rest[[1]]},
  {Flatten[{{first}, keep}, 1], select[Drop[rest, 1], first[[1]]]}]
```

The differences are more of style than of essence: I've pulled `threshold` out of the list that `NestWhile` operates on; I've split the functionality associated with `Select` into a part that performs the selection (`select`) and a part that tests for what to select (`selectQ`); finally, I've disposed of the 'calls' to `Prepend` and `Delete` that seemed (to me) superfluous.